# Doxygen OS X app crashes on launch (10.6.8)

Tags: macos, doxygen, doxywizard

Has anyone successfully launched Doxygen 1.8.7 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8?  After following the simple "drag-to-applications-folder" installation, double-clicking causes the app to immediately crash (in DoxyWizard?) with no backtrace:

```
Process:         launchd [69602]
Path:            /Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/MacOS/Doxywizard
Identifier:      org.doxygen
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [125]

Date/Time:       2014-05-12 09:21:11.464 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          1152 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           2
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008fe01030
Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0x00000000  esp: 0x00000000
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x8fe01030   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000000
  cr2: 0x8fe01030

Binary images description not available
```

Perhaps there's more to the install process?  DO UNIX binaries need to be built in order for the UI app to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxywizard 1.8.7 and its library dependencies were built with a deployment target of 10.9:

```
$ otool -l Doxygen.app/Contents/MacOS/Doxywizard | fgrep --after-context=3 LC_VERSION_MIN
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.9
      sdk 10.9
```

This means the application can only be run on a system running OS X 10.9 or later. Either support for older operating systems was removed in this release or the binaries were accidentally built with an incorrect deployment target.

Comment: the download site says it's for Intel 10.5 or greater.  Must be a mistake, because I doubt anyone would intentionally do a build limited to a single OS.  Wonder if I can get an earlier binary distribution?

Comment: Not sure about a binary, but I did have success compiling `1_8_9_1` release on snow leopard. https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/archive/Release_1_8_9_1.tar.gz; A simple `./configure` `make` and `sudo make install` did the trick. (have xcode 4.2 installed though)

Comment: I tried to compile the wizard, but was having issues. I investigated and found this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/rel-1.8.9.1/Doxygen-1.8.9.1.dmg/download -- I launched it and it successfully presented a window, haven't tested it further yet, but it may help.